# Javascript Custom HTMLElement issue

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a custom 'Counter' component with HTMLElement

Here is the HTML for this component:

```
<template id="counter-template">
  <div class='counter__wrapper'>
    <h2 id='counter__status'></h2>
    <button id='continue'>Continue</button>
    <button id='stop'>Stop</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script src="Counter.js"></script>
```

and the Counter.js code:

```
const currentDocument = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;

class CustomCounter extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.count = 0;
    this.enableCount = true;
  }

  static get observedAttributes() { 
    return ["count"]; 
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (this.enableCount) {
      this.count = newValue;
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#counter__status').innerHTML = this.count;
    }
  }


  connectedCallback() {
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    const template = currentDocument.querySelector('#counter-template');
    const instance = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    shadowRoot.appendChild(instance);

    this.setAttribute('count', this.count);
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.enableCount = false;
    })
  }

}

customElements.define('custom-counter', CustomCounter);
```

The component is working fine, but I'm using it in a setInterval function, where I am setting the 'count' attribute to the interval's iterator, like this:

```
  var counter = document.querySelector('custom-counter');
  var i = 1;
  var completedAt = 10;

  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    counter.setAttribute('count', i);
    if (i == completedAt) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    i++;
}, 1000);
```

and it's working fine, the 'count' attribute is changing and being displayed in the html.

Now, the problem is that I need to stop the counter when I click the 'stop' button, and as you can see I've added a click listener in the   connectedCallback() that will set the value of this.enableCount to false,

and despite having an if statement to check this.enableCount before updating the html in attributeChangedCallback()

```
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (this.enableCount) {  // <==== THIS ONE
      this.count = newValue;
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#counter__status').innerHTML = this.count;
    }
  }
```

The count does not stop when I click the stop button.
(If I console.log the value of this.enableCount it's giving me false, but the count does not stop updating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `this` problem.

Inside your anonymous click handler function

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.enableCount = false;
})
```

`this` is not your webcomponent, but the button being clicked. You can fix that in three ways:

a) Use an arrow function which does not have a `this` of its own:

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.enableCount = false;
})
```

b) Explicitly state what `this` inside your handler function should be by using `Function.prototype.bind()`:

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.enableCount = false;
}.bind(this))
```

c) Use a closure and define a correctly scoped variable holding a reference to `this`:

```
const self = this;
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', function() {
  self.enableCount = false;
})
```

Comment: Thanks, 'this' was referring to the button being clicked.